# Wrong spelling that may change meaning

Tags: hadith, islamic-basis

Assalaam Aalaikum to all my brothers and sisters.

In our day to day life, we chat Islamic words in English.
For e.g **Allahu Akbar** and many more.

Once I was chatting with my teacher and said **inshaAllah** I will come for lecture tomorrow
Then suddenly sent me an image stating a difference which I forget.

The image said that **inshaAllah** have different meaning which may lead to sin.
The correct spelling **in shaa Allah**.

So my question:

> **What is correct spelling and do we commit any sin by spelling it wrongly?Let us know meaning of wrong spelling.**

Jazak Allah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct spelling is, quite simply, إن شاء الله.  There is no "Islamic standard" to transliteration; I don't even know if English letters were even *known* in Arabia during the time of the prophet.

The Wikipedia page on [Arabic romanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic) lists *eighteen* different standards, and there's no reason to believe this is comprehensive. Depending on the system you use, it could be spelt anywhere from "en xAe Allh" to "in sha' Allah" to "in ʃæʔ ʔɑlˤˈlˤɑːh".

Many transliteration systems trade off precision for convenience (just try typing "in ʃæʔ ʔɑlˤˈlˤɑːh" in a text message one of these days), and it is not uncommon for a written phrase to have more than one potential meaning when re-transliterated back to pure Arabic.  But while it's still important not to write (even accidentally) something that will lead to sin, claiming that there is only one "right" way to write Arabic using English letters is wholly unfounded.

Comment: but can u tell me meaning of inshaAllah....is it making us to commit sin??

Comment: @ShoaibChikate The common understanding I've seen is that it *could* mean "إنشاء الله" (Create Allah) instead, but that's only based on the fact that the first two words "in shaa'a" (If...wills) can be confused as one word "inshaa'i" (Create).  The vowel at the end of the verb would still be different though afaik, so it would still be a grammatically incorrect mistake to make.